# Proprietary desktop application that works with AGPL-licensed server application

Tags: agpl-3.0, proprietary-code

I'm programming a desktop application that's proprietary. On my server, it will run application with the AGPL (Affero General Public License). Server app will process the data that will come through the API (part of the server application) and return the modified data using JSON. I do not plan to edit the server application anyway.

So I want to ask whether it is possible to develop a proprietary desktop application that will work with server API, do not break the license? It's necessarily publish the source code of my desktop application?

Comment: What is the AGPL-licensed server backend in question?

Answer (score 3):

> So I want to ask whether it is possible to develop a proprietary desktop application that will work with server API, do not break the license? It's necessarily publish the source code of my desktop application?

These are separate programs. The server-side may need source code redistribution in some cases (at least when modified). The desktop application would not.